# KDE screen saver passes key pressed to program

Tags: kde, screensaver

I've noticed that when screen saver (turn-off screen) is running and I press a key to activate screen again the key is passed to program that is active. This is problem, if I press Del key to activate screen and file manager is active I will get some file deleted. This is not safe at all. Why it is done this way and how to avoid it?

Comment: Are you sure it is really screensaver or is it just DPMS going off? About DPMS: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling

Comment: ok its seems it is DPMS